# Perl counter in hash of hash

Tags: perl, hash

I have a file looking like this:

```
1   1  A12P P1234
1   0  A52Q P1234
1   1  M12P P8866
1   1  R50T P1222
1   1  A82L P8866
0   0  D83F P8866
....
```

in a perl loop, I parse each line and save each column value:

```
while (<FILE>){
     ...
     my $actual=$1; my $predicted=$2; $mutation=$3; $id=$4; 
        if ($actual==1) {
            if ($predicted==1)   { $hash{$id}{$truep}++; } 
            elsif ($predicted==0){ $hash{$id}{$falsen}++; } 
        } elsif ($actual==0) {
            if ($predicted==0)   { $hash{$id}{$truen}++; } 
            elsif ($predicted==1){ $hash{$id}{$falsep}++; } 
        }
}

for $id (keys %hash) {
        $tp = $hash{$id}{$truep};
        $tn = $hash{$id}{$truen};
        $fp = $hash{$id}{$falsep};
        $fn = $hash{$id}{$falsen};
        ...
    }
```

I would expect that, for P8866:

```
$hash{$id}{$fp} --> FP = 0
$hash{$id}{$tp} --> TP = 2
$hash{$id}{$fn} --> FN = 0
$hash{$id}{$tn} --> TN = 1
```

I would expect that, for P1234:

```
$hash{$id}{$fp} --> FP = 0
$hash{$id}{$tp} --> TP = 1
$hash{$id}{$fn} --> FN = 1
$hash{$id}{$tn} --> TN = 0
```

But it doesn't give me the expected values. did I define the hash incorrectly? is there a better way to parse the file?

Comment: There is not enough information included in your question to help debug your issue. What pattern are you using to capture the values of `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, and `$4`? Also what do you expect the output to be? What are the values of `$truep` and `$falsen`?

Comment: The file is actually more complex, that's why I didn't write down the pattern. But I previously checked it and it works. Each element is identified. But I think that the counter is somehow adding values without taking `$id` key into account.

Comment: It might be, you may be right. But we can't tell, given this sample, whether that's happening or _how_ it's happening. I would _guess_ you're hitting a selection/conversion problem. (e.g. check that you've got _literally_ what you expect for the first two values, and the pattern is being anchored properly etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you really want tn, etc., to be constants and not variables, you need to initialize all 4 for each id to get 0's in the hash-of-hashes.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys=1;

my %hash;
while (<DATA>){
    chomp;
    my ($actual, $predicted, $mutation, $id) = split;
    for my $type (qw(tn tp fn fp)) {
        $hash{$id}{$type} = 0 unless exists $hash{$id}{$type}; 
    }
    if (($actual == 1) and ($predicted == 1)) {
        $hash{$id}{tp}++;
    }
    elsif (($actual == 1) and ($predicted == 0)) {
        $hash{$id}{fn}++;
    }
    elsif (($actual == 0) and ($predicted == 0)) {
        $hash{$id}{tn}++;
    }
    elsif (($actual == 0) and ($predicted == 1)) {
        $hash{$id}{fp}++;
    }
}

print Dumper(\%hash);

__DATA__
1   1  A12P P1234
1   0  A52Q P1234
1   1  M12P P8866
1   1  R50T P1222
1   1  A82L P8866
0   0  D83F P8866
```

Prints:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'P1222' => {
                       'fn' => 0,
                       'fp' => 0,
                       'tn' => 0,
                       'tp' => 1
                     },
          'P1234' => {
                       'fn' => 1,
                       'fp' => 0,
                       'tn' => 0,
                       'tp' => 1
                     },
          'P8866' => {
                       'fn' => 0,
                       'fp' => 0,
                       'tn' => 1,
                       'tp' => 2
                     }
        };
```